# Sending complex JSON with fetch, save, and delete on a model or collection

Tags: json, backbone.js, marionette

We have an internal API that was specifically built to be used with a new piece of software I'm building that runs on Backbone. The API has a single URL and takes JSON as input to determine what it needs to return. It essentially allows me to build custom queries with JSON that return exactly what I'm looking for.

Thing is this JSON can get pretty verbose and is often 3–4 levels deep, but sometimes may just be a few lines and just 1 level deep.

First question first: How do I send a string of JSON along with the ID when I do a `fetch()`? Do I have to set these parameters as the model or collection's defaults?

Here is an example of a really simple string to get a specific user's info

```
{
    "which" : "object",
    "object" : {
        "type" : "customer",
        "place" : "store",
        "customerID" : "14"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Backbone with a non-RESTful service, you are going to have a bad time.  It's certainly doable but you'll be missing out on most of the benefits of Backbone.  Turn back now before it's too late and build a RESTful API.

Comment: What is the best resource to start reading up on RESTful services?

Comment: It looks like you're developing a SOAP-like API using JSON, and as Robert says: you're going to have a really bad time. Backbone was made to work with RESTful resources (more specifically, Rails) and therefore make that the default (and easiest) way to use it. One resource to start learning what RESTful APIs look like is Rails documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Should you add that as the final answer or would it better to close this one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested it will likely be challenging to work with SOAP, but it shouldn't be impossible. Backbone models and collections communicate with the server through the `sync` operation; you should be able to customize that. I think something along these lines might get the ball rolling (for models):

```
Backbone.SoapyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        // force POST for all SOAP calls
        method = 'create';

        options = _.extend(options, {
            // Setting the data property will send the model's state
            // to the server. Add whatever complexity is needed here:
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "which" : "object",
                "object" : model.toJSON()
            }),

            // Set the request's content type
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });

        // Defer the rest to Backbone
        return Backbone.sync.apply(this, [method, model, options]);
    }
});

var SoapyModelImpl = Backbone.SoapyModel.extend({
    url: '/test'
});

var soapTest = new SoapyModelImpl({
    id: 42,
    name: 'bob',
    address: '12345 W Street Dr',
    phone: '867 5304'
});

soapTest.fetch();
```